# Error al implementar ToolBar

Tags: android-studio, xml, toolbar

Estoy siguiendo los pasos de [configuración de la barra de app](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up.html) a lo cual al momento de agregar lo siguiente en el archivo xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
```

me sale el siguiente error.

```
The following classes could not be found:
- android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)
Tip: Try to build the project.   
Tip: Try to refresh the layout.
```

en mi archivo gradle tengo lo siguiente

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha04'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revisando el archivo **gradle** me di cuenta que el proyecto se migro a androidx
por lo tanto `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` no funciona a lo cual lo correcto para cuando se migra a androidx es de la siguiente manera `androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar`
quedando de la siguiente manera

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
```

De esta manera logre resolver el problema, si hay algo que este mal o se deba cambiar favor comentar o colocar su respuesta.